# Custom Pagination in Sharepoint DVWP

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a DVWP. Using Sharepoint Designer, I have given pagination and set the rowset value to 10.

But I would like to have a dropdown which would specify, how many rows I need to show at a time, so that user can customize the pagination directly from the page.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up the DVWP to accept a parameter on the Query String rather than being a set number. It will require some manual editing of the XSL, but it's not too onerous.